# Maple : integer equation without explicit delimiters

Tags: int, maple

I would like to calculate an integer in Maple without explicit delimiters. For example, I would like to have the result of this formula :

```
int(cos(a+b*x),x=0...t))
```

where t referred to none number.

The error message is : "Error, unable to match delimiters".

Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command has an extra right parenthesis at the end. That is all that the error message is refering to.